# HTTP Response Filter in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, http, tomcat9

I have a website like http://example.com and there are a lot of URL under my website (http://example.com/a, /ab, /abc, etc.).

Also assume that there are a lot of view files (x.html, y.html, etc.) under my resources file in spring boot project.

I deployed it in Tomcat9 in Centos server.

I want to build something like:

- if (HTTPResponse!=200) -> route to x.html (all the responses of requests incoming all URLs in my project)
- else -> process normal HTTP Request Response Flow

There are some ways : Handle it in `Interceptor` class, `Filter` class, also `@ControllerAdvice` make some part of what I want (I Built).

So I never want to show HTTP error in my website. If it has got an HTTP error, route it to my x.hmtl page else process regular Req-Resp flow.

What is the best way to build it? What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionController {
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public ModelAndView handleError(HttpServletRequest request, Exception e)   {
    Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Request: " + request.getRequestURL() + " raised " + e);
    return new ModelAndView("error");
}

@ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
public ModelAndView handleError404(HttpServletRequest request, Exception e)   
{
    Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Request: " + request.getRequestURL() + " raised " + e);
    return new ModelAndView("404");
}
}
```

Comment: I know this way.But we cannot catch and route to a page if HTTP Response Status is 400 (Bad Request) .Thank You